# Issue executing python script in Docker

Tags: python, docker

I'm starting with Docker. I have started with a Hello World script in Python 3. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3


COPY . hello.py


CMD python3 hello.py
```

In the same directory, I have this python script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello World!");
```

I have built the image with this command:

```
docker build -t home/ubuntu-python-hello .
```

So far, so good. But when I try to run the script with this command:

```
docker run home/ubuntu-python-hello
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in 'hello.py'
```

What am I doing wrong? Any advice or suggestion is accepted, I'm just a newbie.

Thanks.

Comment: try: `COPY hello.py hello.py`

Comment: Look like you copy current folder to folder `hello.py` (in docker container)

Comment: Thank you very much! I though that first argument was the target directory and the second the source! Post it as answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Gerrat, I solved it this way:

```
COPY hello.py hello.py
```

instead of

```
COPY . hello.py
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to install python this way and confirm it with the -y.

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3-dev -y

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - for instance, does the error point to the fact that python is not installed, to which this is a solution?